# Update a label on aspx page before a Response.Redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following redirect but need to change the label to say "Success" before the re-direct:

```
Response.Redirect(Url)
```

I've tried passing in false and then changing the label.Text = "Success"

Also tried saving a value like this

What you need is a way to save data during transition. So the first time the validation is passed store the values into Session variable without success.

```
Session ("label") = "Success
Response.Redirect(Url, False)


Label.Text = Session("label")
```

Is the only way to do this through a java script?

Would I use:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
```

Comment: What problems are you having with this?

Comment: What the point to update the text and make redirect ? the user is not going to see it - maybe you like to show some kind of a message, then if the user close it you make the redirect, or show the message, and with a timer of a javascript make the redirect.

Comment: You cannot show something on a page that will not be rendered since you're redirecting to another page. But using the session to maintain the text should work. You could read that session-value on the redirect-page and show it there. What problem did you have?

Comment: Could you provide the context in which you are trying to accomplish this? It might be helpful in determining a solution.

Comment: The redirect actually loads an excel or word document and so there isn't really a change of page as such ( I didn't write the code)

Comment: If what you're saying is that the redirect opens a document but this page remains visible to the user then I would say yes, use javascript to change the label (to inform them of success) and then open the document as you are doing. Changing the label will not become visible unless a postback takes place on the page.

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought was the case

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "anyKey", "<script>alert('Success'); window.open(" + url + ");</script>", false);
```

or if you want to open the url when user presses ok button on your message box, you can also do it like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "anyKey", "<script>if(confirm('Success')) window.open(" + url + ");</script>", false);
```

also, as Aristo says above

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "anyKey", "<script>$('#"+ lblYourLabel.ClientID +"').val('Success'); var t=setTimeout(function(){window.open(" + url + ");},3000);</script>", false);
```